# RDP into Linux Instance AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS.
I created a Linux free tier instance and its up and running as i am able to access it via ssh putty as i am a windows user.

Now, I wanted to RDP the Linux Instance to see the interface but i am unable to do so. I am unable to find any option for that. 
As per my understanding by reading online forms, it is not possible to RDP LinuxInstance on AWS.

If anyone can give there expert opinion if it is possible to RDP the Linux Instance? If not then Is there any way I can access the graphical interface for Linux Instance in AWS or I just have to work with command line interface from my local machine?

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu, you can install server-side and client-side components that will support remote access to the Ubuntu GUI. See https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-to-ubuntu-1604-windows/.

Answer (score 4):

Amazon had a page that described how to do this with various linux versions but they took it down.  Here are the steps for Linux 16.04.  I just did this on a new ubuntu ec2 instance and it worked fine.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo sed -i 's/^PasswordAuthentication no/PasswordAuthentication yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
sudo passwd ubuntu
sudo apt install xrdp xfce4 xfce4-goodies tightvncserver -y
echo xfce4-session> /home/ubuntu/.xsession
sudo cp /home/ubuntu/.xsession /etc/skel
sudo sed -i '0,/-1/s//ask-1/' /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
sudo service xrdp restart
```

Comment: Second-to-last line gave the following: `sed -i '0,/-1/s//ask-1/' /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
sed: can't read /etc/xrdp/xrdp.inisudo: No such file or directory
sed: can't read sed: No such file or directory
sed: can't read 0,/-1/s//ask-1/: No such file or directory`

Comment: But otherwise, works as promised! Although I had to use port '-l' instead of port 3389 in the dialog box (which was actually the default, but not what I was expecting)

Comment: Worked OK for me, copying and pasting line for line. I didn't get the error described by @StackG, and presumably this is why port 3389 also worked fine for me.
I used the Ubuntu bionic 18.04 amd64 AMI (the latest Ubuntu one)
After you've gone through the steps you then have to open up port 3389 and you can now connect with RDP and log in with username 'ubuntu' and the password you create at step 4. Lovely stuff.

Comment: Above solution works as of 26th November 2019 with Ubuntu 18.04 AMI. However one important missing step that took me 3 days to discover : in your inbound rules (Security groups), one must add the following inbound rule : Type(SSH)/Protocol(TCP)/PortRange(3389)/Source(0.0.0.0/0). The source can be changed to your ip range if desired (more secured)

Comment: i get an error : **Unable to determine failsafe session name.  Possible causes: xfconfd isn't running (D-Bus setup problem); environment variable $XDG_CONFIG_DIRS is set incorrectly (must include "/etc"), or xfce4-session is installed incorrectly**

Answer (score 1):

RDP is a proprietary protocol developed by Microsoft, Linux servers do not come in with GUI, you need to SSH into Linux box and then install packages to enable desktop GUI functionality

Here is an article from AWS
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-ec2-centos-windows/

Note: Amazon Linux does not provide any desktop GUI functionality

Comment: Thanks. I also want to know that the converse is also true? i.e For Windows Instances, Can we ssh them?

Comment: Yes, you can install an open-ssh server on a windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

try install GNOME packages i.e.,

```
$sudo yum -y groupinstall "Server with GUI"
$sudo systemctl enable xrdp; systemctl start xrdp
```

now try login from your windows machine using "windows remote desktop or any vnc client